# Null value passed in nested relation entity - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I was trying to save the user object along with address. Inside `User` class, I have define relationship with `Address`. Inside `Address`, I have defined `User`.

When create object and trying to save it to database, get the following error:

> SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint

```
@Entity
class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String address;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    //getter setter
}
```

User class;

```
class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Address> address;

    //Other fields, getters, & setters
}
```

UserService class;

```
class UserService {

    public long createUser(User user) {

        User u = new User();
        Address address = new Address();
        address.setAddress("Windsong Palace");
        address.setZipCode("239749");

        List<Address> adds = new ArrayList<>();
        adds.add(address);

        u.setAddress(adds);
        //userRepository is the interface extends from JpaRepository<User, Long>
        userRepository.save(u);
    }
}
```

How to pass `user_id` after being created to `Address` class?

Comment: When you are persisting user, it should also persist the associated address objects with relations. And so far your entity mapping looks good. What are you missing ? Whats not happening ?

Comment: I was not aware that liquibase would cause the issue. I was using liquibase, when disabling liquibase, I solved the problem.

Comment: great. Its better now if you answer your own question about this findings so that others dont get confused.

Answer (score 2):

The error indicates, that your address objects do not have a reference to a user object.

If you look at your code, you do not set the user for the address field. Try this:

```
...
address.setAddress("Windsong Palace");
address.setZipCode("239749");
address.setUser(u);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the issue. It was due to liquibase. I was using liquibase with my application. In liquibase `xml` file, I created tables `User`, `Address`. In `application.properties`, `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none`.

But at the time of creating user and address. The repository's `save` could not insert `user_id` in `Address`, it was inserting `null`.

Turning `liquibase.enabled=false` (Removing liquibase) solved the issue.

I think this is not a better solution. But, its working without liquibase.